# Show that $\dfrac{x^2-6x+9}{\sqrt{x^2-6x+13}-2}=\sqrt{(x-3)^2+4}+2$ and hence find the limit as x tends to 3.

Tags: limits

Show that $\dfrac{x^2-6x+9}{\sqrt{x^2-6x+13}-2}=\sqrt{(x-3)^2+4}+2$ and hence find the limit as x tends to 3.

How do I start with this question? Rationalising the denominator? But how would I expand it?

Comment: Yes, rationalize the denominator. Do you know what the conjugate is? (Remember that $(a+\sqrt b)(a-\sqrt b)=a^2-b$, because of the difference-between-two-squares formula (or FOIL, if that's easier for you).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. You want to use the identity $$a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$$ In your case $a:=\sqrt{x^2-6x+13}$ and $b=2$. The expansion is $$\left(\sqrt{x^2-6x+13}-2\right)\cdot\left(\sqrt{x^2-6x+13}+2\right)=x^2-6x+13-4=x^2-6x+9$$ Now, this simplifies significantly with the term in the numerator (but do not forget to multiply the numerator with the conjugate as well).

Comment: I'm not actually sure how to expand brackets if there's are multiple terms in a square root... can I say: let $y=\sqrt{x^2-6x+13}$ and expand it as $(y-2)(y+2)$?

edit: oh, just saw your edit.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{x^2-6x+9}{\sqrt{x^2-6x+13}-2}=\frac{(x-3)^2}{\sqrt{(x-3)^2+4}-2}$$ $$\frac{(x-3)^2}{\sqrt{(x-3)^2+4}-2}*\frac{\sqrt{(x-3)^2+4}+2}{\sqrt{(x-3)^2+4}+2}$$ $$\frac{(x-3)^2}{\sqrt{(x-3)^2+4}-2}*\frac{\sqrt{(x-3)^2+4}+2}{\sqrt{(x-3)^2+4}+2}=\frac{(x-3)^2\sqrt{(x-3)^2+4}+2(x-3)^2}{(x-3)^2}$$ $$\frac{(x-3)^2\sqrt{(x-3)^2+4}+2(x-3)^2}{(x-3)^2}=\sqrt{(x-3)^2+4}+2$$